# Can't overload BulletedList OnClick event (BulletedListEventHandler)

Tags: c#, asp.net, overloading

I'm stuck with a

> CS0123 no overload matches delegate 'BulletedListEventHandler'

error when page loading, whereas I can't see any problem ... I hope your eyes could help me :p

Here is my front code :

```
<div class="ListHyperLink"">
    <asp:BulletedList runat="server" ID="Liste_Documents_Utiles" DisplayMode="HyperLink" OnClick="ItemsBulletedList_Click"></asp:BulletedList>
</div>
```

Then I fill in the control with a databind (block code not relevant here I guess) and here is the code-behind block I'd like to fire while selecting an HyperLink from the bulletedList :

```
  public void ItemsBulletedList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventHandler e)
{
    HyperLink lienATelecharge = (HyperLink) e.Target;
    DownloadFile download_file = new DownloadFile(this, lienATelecharge.NavigateUrl.Replace(@"\", "/"));
}
```

I checked replacing with a simple EventArgs and linking to a asp:button OnClick and the event does fire. So the error doesn't seem to come out from somewhere else...

**EDIT thanks to Brian Mains answer :**

Here is my new code :

```
 public void LinkBulletedList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
    int index = e.Index;

    ListItem lienATelecharge = (ListItem)Liste_Documents_Utiles.Items[index];

    DownloadFile download_file = new DownloadFile(this, Liste_Documents_Utiles.Value);
}
```

And then pass DisplayMode="HyperLink" to DisplayMode="LinkButton".

Comment: What is `e.Target`? `BulletedListEventHandler` class does not have any such property.

Comment: Yes it does, Autocompletion suggested it. However BulletedListEventArgs doesn't :)

Comment: DUH! And I never noticied you have `BulletedListEventHandler` instead of `BulletedListEventHandler` :D Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
public void ItemsBulletedList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventHandler e)
```

to:

```
public void ItemsBulletedList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
```

Comment: OMG that's it, thanks a lot ! Moreover, I have discovered you need to be in DisplayMode="LinkButton" to fire the event.